# Rendering Line Art modifier from a distance Bug?

Tags: camera, lineart

I tried importing the same assets to a new scene and it worked just fine? Whats the problem here... I also heard of using freestyle which does kind of solve it but also adds 20 seconds to the render which I want to avoid.[image]

Comment: Try to increase your camera clipping distances.

Comment: i tried that, it didnt fix anything.